# Magento multi-store loading in frameset(<iframe>)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I created Multi-store in Magneto. The Multi-store initially works correctly.

But now that page loading in frameset(`<iframe>`), i don't why loading like that.

My Multi-store have separate domain.In that all controller route to 404.

I don't know any changes done in admin panel for Multi-store.

Any help my appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to understand what you are trying to ask, but I can have a crack at it :-)

You have Magento store pages being displayed within an iframe running on a separate domain.

If this is the case, you will find that IE will block the Magento page from being displayed due to it's restriction on third party cookies created within framesets.

To get around this issue, you can set a php P3P header in your index.php to tell IE that your privacy policy says that this is acceptable:

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```